# Min and Max validation in ngmodel

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

I have html code snippet as following:

```
<mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Interest</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="number" [(ngModel)]="percentage" required>
      </mat-form-field>
```

The input number should be between 1 to 100. How can I add mat-error to this validation?

Answer (score 0):

first add these script references in your head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.12/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.2.2/angular-material.min.css"></script>
```

next add an angularjs app and controller. you can do this in  tag or separate file then reference it your html:

```
   var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);

   app.controller("MyCtrl", ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {}]);
```

finally add a form and inside it an input with type number which min, max, required properties are set and has a name.

```
   <form method="post" name="form1" >
                <md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block input-texts">
                    <label>input a number</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Number" ng-model="Number" required autofocus min="1" max="100" />
                    <div ng-messages="form1.Number.$error">
                        <div ng-message="required">please enter a number.</div>
                        <div ng-message="min">please enter a number greater than 1.</div>
                        <div ng-message="max">please enter a number smaller than 100.</div>
                    </div>
                </md-input-container>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" ng-disabled="form1.Number.$invalid">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Submit
                </button>
            </form>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);

        app.controller("MyCtrl", ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
        }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.12/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.2.2/angular-material.min.css"></script>

</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <form method="post" name="form1" >
                <md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block input-texts">
                    <label>input a number</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Number" ng-model="Number" required autofocus min="1" max="100" />
                    <div ng-messages="form1.Number.$error">
                        <div ng-message="required">please enter a number.</div>
                        <div ng-message="min">please enter a number greater than 1.</div>
                        <div ng-message="max">please enter a number smaller than 100.</div>
                    </div>
                </md-input-container>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" ng-disabled="form1.Number.$invalid">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Submit
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

set type = range, where min represent initial limit and max represent final limit like this :

```
 <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Interest</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="range" min="0" max="100" [(ngModel)]="percentage" required>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: You should explain your code to improve the quality of the anwer.